# mongodb js easy sort method on the fly

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following output from the mongo shell :

```
mongos> var test=db.collection.stats().shards;for(key in test) printjson( key +" -> "+ 
 test[key].totalIndexSize)
"shard0_v2 -> 24782991360"
"shard4_v2 -> 36988542976"
"shard2_v2 -> 27401830400"
"shard3_v2 -> 21079486464"
"shard1_v2 -> 21052264448"
mongos>
```

I need the output sorted as follow:

```
"shard0_v2 -> 24782991360"
"shard1_v2 -> 21052264448"
"shard2_v2 -> 27401830400"
"shard3_v2 -> 21079486464"
"shard4_v2 -> 36988542976"
```

Please, advice some quick and easy option in the mongo shell?

Comment: I think an aggregation would do the trick (`$unwind` operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#examples)

Comment: I need to do in js , since the stats is not array originally and it will need too much transformations with aggregaton stages

Comment: Quick and dirty: I'd suggest you to create an array with your lines instead of printing them. Then, you could sort the array with sort() https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely try to make an aggregation since the framework is done for this.

But if you want something that is quick and dirty:

Assuming:

```
test = {
          "shard0_v2": {
              "totalIndexSize": 24782991360 
          }, 
          //... others objects
      }
```

The solution would be:

```
Object.keys(test)
    .map((shardId) => {
        return `${shardId} -> ${test[shardId].totalIndexSize}`;
    })
    .sort()
    .forEach((line) => console.log(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mcanzerini , ended up with this:

```
 mongos> var x=[];var test=db.collection.stats().shards;for(key in test) x.push( 
key+"->"+test[key].totalIndexSize);x.sort()
[
    "shard0_v2->24783155200",
    "shard1_v2->36988542976",
    "shard2_v2->27401818112",
    "shard3_v2->21068120064",
    "shard4_v2->21080612864"
]
mongos>
```

Yours also work well:

```
mongos> var test=db.collection.stats().shards;Object.keys(test).map((shardId) => {return `${shardId} -> ${test[shardId].totalIndexSize}`;}).sort().forEach(function(line){print(line)})
shard0_v2 -> 24783155200
shard1_v2 -> 36988542976
shard2_v2 -> 27401818112
shard3_v2 -> 21071474688
shard4_v2 -> 21080666112
mongos>
```